# How do you link your Twitter account with Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, twitter

I found a blog that shows all the top Stack Overflow users' Twitter profiles....

http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/105/twitter-accounts-for-all-stackoverflow-users-by-reputation

How do you link your Twitter account to your Stack Overflow profile?

Comment: Note: that list is based on the November data dump, changing your profile now will only be reflected if that SO-Twitter list is updated from the next data dump.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no official way to link your Twitter account to your Stack Overflow profile.

[image]

To show up in those lists, just add your Twitter account link to your *About me* description in [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147153/digiguru). It worked [for me](http://brianbondy.com/stackexchange-twitter/stackapps/).

> If you'd like to have your account
>   listed in the directories, simply make
>   sure your Twitter account is linked
>   somewhere in your profile, and I'll
>   update these lists again on a future
>   data dump.

Comment: That's correct I just parse the about of each user for twitter links.

Answer (score 3):

1. "Edit Profile & Settings",
2. navigate to section "Web presence",
3. add meaningful info to "Twitter link or username".